# MYSQL Joining 3 tables by sequence

Tags: mysql, join

I'm gonna try to joining 3 tables by sequence,

Table 1

```
CREATE TABLE table_1(tb1_id int,rpp_id int);
```

```
INSERT INTO table_1(tb1_id,rpp_id) VALUES ('1','127');
```

| tb1_id | rpp_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 127 |

Table 2

```
CREATE TABLE table_2(rpp_id int,sequence int);
```

```
INSERT INTO table_2(rpp_id,sequence) VALUES 
('127','1'),
('127','1'),
('127','1'),
('127','1'),
('127','1'),
('127','2'),
('127','3');
```

| rpp_id | sequence |
| --- | --- |
| 127 | 1 |
| 127 | 1 |
| 127 | 1 |
| 127 | 1 |
| 127 | 1 |
| 127 | 2 |
| 127 | 3 |

Table 3

```
CREATE TABLE table_3(tb3_id int,rpp_id int,code_generate VARCHAR(100));
```

```
INSERT INTO table_2(tb3_id,rpp_id,sequence) VALUES 
('1','127','PL.461'),
('2','127','PL.428'),
('3','127','PL.319'),
('4','127','PL.306'),
('5','127','PL.301'),
('6','127','PL.292'),
('7','127','PL.291');
```

| tb3_id | rpp_id | code_generate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 127 | PL.461 |
| 2 | 127 | PL.428 |
| 3 | 127 | PL.319 |
| 4 | 127 | PL.306 |
| 5 | 127 | PL.301 |
| 6 | 127 | PL.292 |
| 7 | 127 | PL.291 |

I've try some query like this

```
SELECT B.`sequence`, C.`code_generate`
FROM table_1 A
LEFT JOIN table_2 B ON B.`rpp_id`= A.`rpp_id`
LEFT JOIN table_3 C ON C.`rpp_id`=B.`rpp_id`
WHERE B.`rpp_id`=127
```

| sequence | code_generate |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | PL.461 |
| 1 | PL.428 |
| 1 | PL.319 |
| 1 | PL.306 |
| 1 | PL.301 |
| 1 | PL.292 |
| 1 | PL.291 |
| 1 | PL.461 |
| 1 | PL.428 |
| 1 | PL.319 |
| 1 | PL.306 |
| 1 | PL.301 |
| 1 | PL.292 |
| 1 | PL.291 |
| 1 | PL.461 |
| 1 | PL.428 |
| 1 | PL.319 |
| 1 | PL.306 |
| 1 | PL.301 |
| 1 | PL.292 |
| 1 | PL.291 |
| 1 | PL.461 |
| 1 | PL.428 |
| 1 | PL.319 |
| 1 | PL.306 |
| 1 | PL.301 |
| 1 | PL.292 |
| 1 | PL.291 |
| 1 | PL.461 |
| 1 | PL.428 |
| 1 | PL.319 |
| 1 | PL.306 |
| 1 | PL.301 |
| 1 | PL.292 |
| 1 | PL.291 |
| 2 | PL.461 |
| 2 | PL.428 |
| 2 | PL.319 |
| 2 | PL.306 |
| 2 | PL.301 |
| 2 | PL.292 |
| 2 | PL.291 |
| 3 | PL.461 |
| 3 | PL.428 |
| 3 | PL.319 |
| 3 | PL.306 |
| 3 | PL.301 |
| 3 | PL.292 |
| 3 | PL.291 |

and the result like this, that not i expected

---

But, im expecting the return of values like below.

| sequence | code_generate |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | PL.461 |
| 1 | PL.428 |
| 1 | PL.319 |
| 1 | PL.306 |
| 1 | PL.301 |
| 2 | PL.292 |
| 3 | PL.291 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need in this:

```sql
WITH
cte_2 AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY rpp_id ORDER BY sequence) rn
    FROM table_2
),
cte_3 AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY rpp_id ORDER BY tb3_id) rn
    FROM table_3
)
SELECT cte_2.sequence, cte_3.code_generate
FROM cte_2
JOIN cte_3 USING (rpp_id, rn)
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e83b4aaae197143ceb9a73184e2d2095

PS. Some DDL/DML are wrong - fixed.

PPS. `table_1` not needed.

Comment: Thank you man, you save my day. I learn new query knowledge about that(ps: im sorry that im newbie on mysql).